# How to create class for storing different types of vertex?

Tags: opengl, c++, architecture, vertex

I am writing graphics engine for educational pursoses and have some problems.

I need to have ability to use different vertex formats (for example position+normal+uv or position+normal+uv+bones+weights).
I have different structs for these formats and have a class HardwareBuffer that stores OpenGL vertex and index buffers. 
The problem is to give this class the ability to work with different types of vertices.
There are a way to make this class template and use like this:

```
HardwareBuffer<VertexPosNormUV> buffer;
buffer.addVertex(VertexPosNormUV(vector3(1, 1, 1), vector3(1, 0, 0), vector2(1, 0)));
```

But in my engine there is an interface IRenderer that have virtual method `drawDataFromHardwaveBuffer`. Also there is a class OpenGLRenderer that is inherited from it. And now I can't pass my hardware buffer object to this method because there isn't a way to use template virtual methods.

```
Renderer renderer = createRenderer(GraphicsDriver::OpenGL3);
renderer->drawDataFromHardwaveBuffer(buffer); // can't make this method template
```

I can write functions for every type of vertex but this is not a solution.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Some questions beforehand:
- Which openGL version?
- Aren't you using VBO's?

Comment: I use OpenGL 3.3 and I use VBO for storing vertex data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not personally a fan of this architectural direction (giving the buffers strong vertex types and using runtime polymorphism in graphics abstractions). That said, a simple solution to this kind of problem is to hide the template argument by working with a base interface class.

In this solution your `HardwareBuffer<T>` type inherits from a `BasicHardwareBuffer` base, which provides the basic methods needed for the `Renderer` to use it. These basic methods are generally just ones that return a pointer to the buffer data (as a `void*` or similar), the size in bytes of the buffer, and some format enumeration that you can map to the underlying format enumeration for the concrete API.

In other words:

```
struct BasicHardwareBuffer {
  void* getBufferData();
  std::size_t getBufferSizeInBytes();
  BufferFormat getBufferFormat();
};
```

`HardwareBuffer` then is-a `BasicHardwareBuffer`:

```
template<typename VertexType>
struct HardwareBuffer : BasicHardwareBuffer {
};
```

`drawDataFromHardwaveBuffer` can take a pointer or reference to a `BasicHardwareBuffer`:

```
void Renderer::drawDataFromHardwaveBuffer(BasicHardwareBuffer& buffer) {
}
```

You can implement `BasicHardwareBuffer`'s methods by requiring the child types pass information about the buffer size and format up from their own constructors:

```
HardwareBuffer<VertexType>::HardwareBuffer(std::size_t elementCount)
: BasicHardwareBuffer(elementCount * sizeof(VertexType), VertexType::Format) {
}
```